# Are there any FHE-MPC schemes implemented?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation

I want to know if there are any publicly available multiparty computation schemes derived from fully homomorphic encryption schemes. An example would be the implementation of this scheme https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/094.pdf.